# Amplifier noise while charging

Tags: amplifier, audio, dc, charge

I have been struggling with this for a while.

I am trying to create a simple stereo system with the PAM8403 amplifier, using a 3.7v lion battery and a 5v charger (both from a powerbank). This is the schematic I used for hooking it up:

[image: Circuit]

This works pretty well, but when I plug in a micro usb charger there is a pretty loud hum noise and sometimes other strange noises.
Seems like some ground problem or interference or something. I have tried adding capcitors and resistors to the power line but that didn't help.
Can anyone explain to me whats happening and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the noise present when you charge from a power bank instead of from a USB phone charger or PC ? If the noise is present independant of the way you charge it is probably the charger circuit. It could be a switching charger. Show a photo of that charger circuit to confoirm this.

Comment: Your schematics does not look right in charger area - it creates an impression that 3.7V is shorted with 5V charger port. Could you please correct your picture?

Comment: You can not safely connect a 3.5 V battery directly across the terminals of a 5 V power supply. You need a charger circuit for your battery and some safe way of switching between the two. The hum and noise is the 5 V power supply trying it's best to blow up the battery. It is overloaded and will not be giving out 5 V and the resultant power line will be full of high-frequency switching noise.

Comment: OP mentions that he uses something from a powerbank for the charge port so I think we can assume there's some circuit present between the 5 V USB port and the battery.

Comment: Sounds like your average audio ground-loop problem. What if you use a floating audio source like a phone or mp3-player?

Comment: @winny, What ground loop? The power source is already floating...

Comment: Which PAM8403 amplifier board do you have? Is it powered directly from the 3.7V battery, or upconverted to 5V via the powerbank circuit?

Comment: Power source as in battery with no charger connected?

Comment: OP fails to clarify what his circuit is doing resulting in an answer that doesn't help much as it is not getting to the root cause. Some questions have been asked in the comments but none have been answered properly. Giving up and moving on...

Answer (score 0):

The hum is caused by battery-to-5V upconverter. It is a switcher with variable ripples, since its main function is charging, which does not care much about ripples.

To reduce the noise you should try a filter, like this, something like two 3.3mH wirewound inductors with a 100uF 6.3V electrolytic capacitor:

[image]

Bigger inductors are better.

ADDITION: It could be that the noise/hum appears when the audio amplifier has no signal and the whole circuit consumes almost no power. In this case the powerbank will operate at very unfavorable low-output conditions, and switching mode may enter some intermediate random pusling state, such that the noise spectrum gets into audio range. The simple solution could be to add a constant resistive load, 100 Ohm or something, to get the powerbank back into normal (fast-switching) mode. Of course, it will drain extra power, but the hum might disappear.

Comment: Wow thanks for the respones. It indeed uses the circuit from the powerbank to charge the battery. Ali Chen, could you be so kind to integrate your solution in my circuit. That would make more sense to me. (eg where the inductors should be placed and where the capacitor should be placed). Thanks.
Oh, and would there be a better solution, for example replacing the charging circuit with something else?

Comment: Voltage symbol on the left represents your powerbank. R1 load represents your amplifier. You probably can find a powerbank with better switcher quality, but I am not sure if this would be a better solution with regard to your budget, since you might need to try several of them.

Comment: Thanks! So that would look like this in the end?
http://oi65.tinypic.com/6qk4zp.jpg

Comment: Yes, like that. But you still didn't fix your short between the 3.7V battery and 5V charger output.

Comment: I'm gonna try this shortly. Thank you very much. So in the end, with charging circuit this should be correct; http://oi63.tinypic.com/296p37t.jpg

Comment: Wait, are you connecting your amp to battery only, and not to 5V charging output? Is 3.7V enough for your PAM8403?

Comment: Yeah its connected to the 3.7v battery, not the 5v output. PAM8403 is rated 2.5v-5v operating voltage.

Comment: Ok, then this is still a noise from lightly loaded 3.7->5V upconverter. It has no load, and therefore operates in odd rare-pulse mode. You can try to load the port with your smartphone to check if the hum changes. The better solution would be to make a mechanical switch, and totally disconnect the charged battery cell from 5V upconverter, and use the internal powerbank circuitry for charging the Li-Ion cell when depleted. But then you will be better off with something like this, http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/300967542514?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true